# Override function (e.g. "alert") and call the original function?

Tags: javascript, overriding

I would like to override a Javascript built-in function with a new version that calls the original (similarly to overriding a method on a class with a version that calls `super` in many languages). How can I do this?

For example...

```
window.alert = function(str) {
    //do something additional
    if(console) console.log(str);

    //super.alert(str) // How do I do this bit?
}
```

Comment: A similar, but slightly more complex case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original

Comment: Shows overriding alert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Comment: I removed the "OO" and "superclass" tags because they did not apply. But this question covers mocking "super" in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885404/javascript-override-methods

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Store a reference to the original function in a variable:

```
(function() {
    var _alert = window.alert;                   // <-- Reference
    window.alert = function(str) {
        // do something additional
        if(console) console.log(str);
        //return _alert.apply(this, arguments);  // <-- The universal method
        _alert(str);                             // Suits for this case
    };
})();
```

The universal way is [`<original_func_reference>.apply(this, arguments)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) - To preserve context and pass all arguments. Usually, the return value of the original method should also be returned.

However, it's known that `alert` is a void function, takes only one argument, and does not use the `this` object. So, `_alert(str)` is sufficient in this case.

Note: IE <= 8 throws an error if you try to overwrite `alert`, so make sure that you're using `window.alert = ...` instead of `alert = ...`.

Comment: Just tested: All major browsers allow the modification of the global `window.alert`, except for IE <= 8. Prior IE 9, an error was thrown when attempting to overwrite `alert`.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the heads-up. Did you notice the IE problem with other built-in funcs?

Comment: @ring0 Basically every built-in: `confirm`, `document`, ... If you want to intercept `window.alert` calls, you can wrap the code in a closure where a custom `window` (or `alert`) variable is declared and defined. This will always work if your application does not rely on implicit variable declaration.

Comment: @RobW even though this post is pretty old, just tested alert override in IE 7.0.6002.18005 (Vista) and IE 8.0.6001.18702 (Win XP) and works in both.

Comment: @JeremyS. Oh, you're right. When I wrote that statement, I used `alert = ....`. This throws an error. But if you use `window.alert = ...`, then everything will work as intended.

Comment: @RobW perfect, can you please remove the note for future readers

Comment: Thats such an Amaaaaaazing way :D

Answer (score 24):

There is no "super". Anyway, create a closure to "keep" around the original function-object.

Note the "self invoking function" that returns a new function-object (that is assigned to the `window.alert` property). The new function-object returned creates a closure around the *variable* `original` which evaluates to the original *value* of `window.alert` that was passed in to the "self invoking function".

```
window.alert = (function (original) {
  return function (str) {
    //do something additional
    if(console) {
      console.log(str)
    }
    original(str)
  }
})(window.alert)
```

However, I *believe* some browsers may prevent `alert` and other built-ins from being modified...

Happy coding.

Comment: This is a very elegant use of a closure. Definitely the smallest closure footprint I have ever seen.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming your question is how do you overwrite a built-in and still be able to call it. First off as a disclaimer, you should never overwrite built ins unless you have a good reason for doing it since it will make it impossible to debug/test.

This is how you would do it:

```
window._alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(str) { 
     if(console) console.log(str);
     window._alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Note: This approach is not easily extensible. Call the same code twice, and you've lost the original method.

Comment: Not if you only set window._alert if it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

How to do simple classical inheritance in Javascript:

```
SuperClass.call(this) // inherit from SuperClass (multiple inheritance yes)
```

How to override functions:

```
this.myFunction = this.myFunction.override(
                    function(){
                      this.superFunction(); // call the overridden function
                    }
                  );
```

The override function is created like this:

```
Function.prototype.override = function(func)
{
 var superFunction = this;
 return function() 
 {
  this.superFunction = superFunction;
  return func.apply(this,arguments);
 };
};
```

Works with multiple arguments.
 
Fails when trying to override undefined or nonfunctions.
Makes "superFunction" a "reserved" word :-)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not use a classical inheritance model. There is a nice [article here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) which describes a way to write your classes so that a similar syntax can be used, but it's not natively supported.

Answer (score 1):

By using proxy object you can do this.

```
window.alert = new Proxy(window.alert , {
apply: function(target,that,args){
    console && console.log(args.join('\n'));
    target.apply(that,args)
}})
```