# How to properly modify the alert function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the contents of the alert before it "alerts".

I have this function:

```
function alert(msg) {

    // THIS WILL CHECK IF THE WORD FUNCTION IS EXISTING IN A STRING
    var searchFunction = jQuery.type(msg);

    if(searchFunction != 'function')
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to "alert" since I modified the alert function already.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to pass a string with the word "function" to this method and what would you do if that is the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427708/override-function-e-g-alert-and-call-the-original-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I don't know how to "alert" since I modified the alert
>   function already.

Before modifying the alert, do this:

```
var myAlert = alert;
```

Now you can do `myAlert("Hi, I am a alert");`