# Decorate prototype and call parent function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to decorate some object for example:

```
Object.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
      return x;
  } 

  return super.someFunc() // <-- ? 
}
```

How can I call the function that I'm overriding, on the second return statement?

Comment: Firsly, you generally shouldn't add to the native Object's prototype, as it can cause issues. Secondly, you'd have to store the old function in a temporary variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override function (e.g. "alert") and call the original function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427708/override-function-e-g-alert-and-call-the-original-function)

Comment: Maybe it should be clearer what you're trying to do with [***super***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) here, as it's a special way to access functions on an object's parent.

Comment: Totally depends on what you mean by "overriding". Are you replacing it? Are you shadowing it in the prototype chain? This is why you need to give an actual, full demonstration of the code. As it is, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take advantage of inheritance:

```
function Parent() { }

Parent.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {
    var result = 0;
    if (x == 1) {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

function Child() { }

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); //inheritance
Child.prototype.constructor = Child; //enforce the constructor to be Child instead of Parent

Child.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {
    return Parent.prototype.someFunc.call(this, x); //call your Parent prototype someFunc passing your current instance
}

var child = new Child();
console.log(child.someFunc(1)); //1
console.log(child.someFunc(2)); //0
```

Avoid to extend native prototypes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 1):

```
var _someFunc = Object.prototype.someFunc;
Object.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {
  // ...
  return _someFunc.call(this, x/*, other args*/);
}
```

Comment: You made a static call for this method. That means that in the function, if you use `this` you will not get the instance you are working on

Comment: Right. Should've used call/apply/bind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a backup. Say:

```
var __superFunc = Object.prototype.someFunc;
Object.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
      return x;
  }

  return __superFunc.call(this, x);
}
```

Comment: `super` is a reserved word.

Comment: wouldnt x need to be passed to __superfunc too? __superfunc(x)

Comment: I doubt the first one will work. `this.prototype.someFunc` doesn't exist.

Comment: Both of you, didn't you see the note?

Comment: @squint Check the above.

Comment: @squint Then I am removing that part.

Comment: @squint Is that okay? Kindly please remove the downvote.

Comment: `this` will never have a `.prototype` property. It will be removed when you create an instance and renamed to `.__proto__` or something.

Comment: @Louy You are right. Anyway, I removed that part. I meant `__proto__` only!!

Comment: You made a static call for this method. That means that in the function, if you use `this` you will not get the instance you are working on

Comment: No. Because 1) that's a private thing you should never use and 2) `__proto__.someFunc` is the new function.

Comment: No. So your solution still doesn't work because you should use `apply/call/bind`. I had that same mistake. (I've remove the downvote already).

Comment: @Louy Sure thanks. I have updated the answer. Got the issue. Would you like to nullify the downvote? `:P` Your wish...

Answer (score -1):

The entire code have to be rewritten; you need to specify the behaviour of the function also for the parent (To prevent recursive calls)... Here is a hint to the soulution, using call method:

```
Object.prototype.someFunc.call(this, x);
```

In javascript, there is no real native implementation of inheritance

Comment: `Object.someFunc` doesn't really exist. `(new Object()).someFunc` do. or `Object.prototype.someFunc`.

Comment: So there's another issue here. When you do `Object.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {...}` the value of `Object.prototype.someFunc` is overriden. You have the capture the previous value before you call it. Your answer will cause an infinite loop and a max stack size error the way it is.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. this code `Object.prototype.someFunc = function(x) {...}` is done once, perhapse in page loading. Then at runtime, when `someFunc` is called on some instance of `Object`, we can do `Object.prototype.someFunc.call(this, x);` . So, I don't catch where could you see any overriding

Comment: @ikken: Drop your code into the original and test it. You'll see that you have a recursive call with no escape condition.

Comment: so OP is asking how to access the original (or **super**) function inside the one which overrides it. you'll need to end up with two functions.

Comment: The entire code have to be rewritten; you need to specify the behaviour of the function also for the parent (To prevent recursive calls).. Here , I gave only a hint to the soulution, (using `call`)