# Override js alerts failing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to override the JS alerts so I can do some stuff before and after each alert. This is what I wrote:

```
var old_alert = alert
var alerting = false
    function alert(message) {
      alerting = true;
      console.info("alert override: alerting");
      var result = old_alert(message);
      alerting = false;
      console.info("alert override: done alerting");
      return result;
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that old_alert somehow points to my new function and I get an infinite recursion error from my browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i believe you have to return false or something like that. Return a value that stops the default execution

Comment: have you tried overriding the alert like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729684/582061 ?

Comment: @StianStandahl I am unable to use jQuerry in my project (as per that answer suggests)

Comment: how about just doing this: window.alert = function(){ //do something } . note i am looking for a way to handle default behavior from inside this function

Comment: here you go. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10427741/582061 note: IE8 throws exception

Comment: well, that helped. Should mark this as a duplicate