# Overriding node eventEmitter.on with closure for logging not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, eventemitter

I'm trying to track down an issue in my SPA where an event is being triggered too many times. With that in mind, I wanted to override node's `eventEmitter.on` function to add some logging in then call the original. This lead me to this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427757/261682 about overriding `window.alert` and I came up with the following code:

```
// Ignore `state` here but it essentially means I can access `eventEmitter` all over my app.
var EventEmitter = ('events')   
state.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
state.eventEmitter.on = (function (original) {
    return function (name, callback) {
        console.log('On Called for %s', name)
        original(name, callback)
    }
})(state.eventEmitter.on)
```

This isn't working. The event isn't triggered at all and I don't see anything in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: There are other ways for me to track my original issue down but I'm interested as to why my code above isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your code and it mostly looks fine, though as I run it I get the following error:

`Cannot read property '_events' of undefined` an internal error of EventEmitter

This is because the way you pass the original `.on()` function it will lose the context (this argument) when being called.

To avoid this bind the function to the event emitter by calling `state.eventEmitter.on.bind(state.eventEmitter)`. I also noticed you forgot the return the result of the original function since `on()` is chainable.

Furthermore if no one is listening to the events your overridden function won't be called as well.

Here's the code with the modifications mentioned above

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
state.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
state.eventEmitter.on = (function (original) {
    return function (name, callback) {
        console.log('On Called for %s', name);
            return original(name, callback);
        }
})(state.eventEmitter.on.bind(state.eventEmitter));

state.eventEmitter.on('my_event', function () {
    console.log('my_event has been called');
});

state.eventEmitter.emit('my_event');
```

With this  got the following output:

```
On Called for my_event
my_event has been called
```

Comment: Amazing! this helped solve my problem I was also looking to call some custom functions after the original function binding is done!