# JS nested inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm not able to properly override an inherited object and wondering if I can get a hand here. Been stuck for 3 days already.

say

```
function Person() { 
    function getValue(){
        serviceArea();
    }

    function serviceArea() {
        alert('Old Location');
    }

    return {
        getValue: getValue,
        serviceArea: serviceArea
    }
}
```

then

```
function Student() {};
Student.prototype = new Person();
Student.prototype.serviceArea = function() { alert('New Location'); };
var bobStu = new Student();
```

when I run `bobStu.serviceArea();` I get `'New Location'`, however when I run `bobStu.getValue();` I get `'Old Location'`

I'm passing this `bobStu.getValue();` down a method that needs to call the overridden method but I can't get it to do that. Can you explain why `getValue()` is calling the old `serviceArea()`? and how to do it properly?

I've been readying this article many times and feel like it is telling me something but I'm too burnt that I can't get it :( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Namespace

Comment: Your `Person` is a factory function, not a classical constructor, and it's scoping does not care about properties.

Comment: You might find the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183011/javascript-redefine-and-override-existing-function-body useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just `serviceArea()` refers only to the function `serviceArea` defined in the scope of `Person`:

```
function Person() { 
    function getValue(){
        serviceArea();  // this...
    }

    // ...always refers to this, independent of the object you're constructing
    function serviceArea() {
        alert('Old Location');
    }

    // also note this:
    this.getValue = getValue;
    this.serviceArea = serviceArea;
}
```

Use `this.serviceArea()` instead if you want to use the `serviceArea` methods implemented by subclasses.

Also, constructors shouldn't return values; attach the values directly to the `this` value instead.