# Overwrite javascript function ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

there is a functionality that i need to change in ag-grid, and for this i need to change a function, for example from:

```
 NumberFilter.prototype.onFilterChanged = function () {

            var filterText = utils_1.default.makeNull(this.eFilterTextField.value);

            if (filterText && filterText.trim() === '') {
                filterText = null;
            }
            var newFilter;
            if (filterText !== null && filterText !== undefined) {

            console.log(filterText);


                newFilter = parseFloat(filterText);
                console.log(newFilter);
            }
            else {
                newFilter = null;
            }
            if (this.filterNumber !== newFilter) {
                this.filterNumber = newFilter;
                this.filterChanged();
            }
        };
```

To

```
 NumberFilter.prototype.onFilterChanged = function () {

            var filterText = utils_1.default.makeNull(this.eFilterTextField.value);

            if (filterText && filterText.trim() === '') {
                filterText = null;
            }
            var newFilter;
            if (filterText !== null && filterText !== undefined) {

            console.log(filterText);

                // replace comma by dot
                newFilter = parseFloat(filterText.replace(/,/g, '.'));
                console.log(newFilter);
            }
            else {
                newFilter = null;
            }
            if (this.filterNumber !== newFilter) {
                this.filterNumber = newFilter;
                this.filterChanged();
            }
        };
```

How can i overwrite the functionality in th ag-grid configuration file?
Above i leave a demo example with the configuration file:

```
Link: https://plnkr.co/edit/LDdrRbANSalvb4Iwh5mp?p=preview
```

Comment: Replacing commas with dots is not a good enough reason to override the internal functions of the grid. Have you tried creating a custom filter that can deal with your number format, as described in the docs?

Comment: @Tomalak and reading the documentation for a small change i need to basically apply all the functionality from the NumberFilter class, so i wonder if there is a way to inherit all his functionality in a new Object and then change his method. I try do for example var CustomNumberFilter = Object.create(NumberFilter); , but doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate here : [Ag-grid inheritate functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818793/ag-grid-inheritate-functionality)

I'm reposting my answer from there

---

You should use Javascript inheritance on NumberFilter and then overtwrite the method onFilterChanged. Check this answer to see how to do it : [JavaScript override methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885404/javascript-override-methods)

Then instead of specifying

```
filter:'number'
```

You can do :

```
filter:new MyNumberFilter();
```

As you can see i instanciated the filter, it's required or you will have the same instance for all your number column's filter on the grid.