# Ag-grid inheritate functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

im creating a custom filter, the functionality is basically the same that is built-in in the ag-grid.

Is the:

```
var NumberFilter = (function () {
        function NumberFilter() {
        }
        NumberFilter.prototype.init
```

The only difference is that i only need to change the function

```
NumberFilter.prototype.onFilterChanged
```

To replace commas by dots. But to overwrite all the methods it doesnt makes much sense, is there a way in inherite the functionality of the filter 'number' and change only the NumberFilter.prototype.onFilterChanged?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript inheritance on NumberFilter and then overtwrite the method onFilterChanged. Check this answer to see how to do it : [JavaScript override methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885404/javascript-override-methods)

Then instead of specifying

```
filter:'number'
```

You can do :

```
filter:new MyNumberFilter();
```

As you can see i instanciated the filter, it's required or you will have the same instance for all your number column's filter on the grid.