# trim() : unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

As you can see in the picture bellow there is an unexpected behavior of the `trim()` function, because is stripping the `á`

[image]

This code is part of javascript file that I've included in many projects without problems, but now a client of mine is facing this issue. The sad part is that i haven't access to the source code project client.

## Questions

1. Is it posible to override the implementation of native trim()
   function in Javascript?
2. What could the reasons of this behavior?

Comment: Where are you running this? I tried in chrome, firefox and Node.js and it seems to work for me.

Comment: not reproducible in chrome `"olá".trim()` btw...

Comment: It is possible to override the `String.prototype.trim` method, but it is **highly discouraged** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885404/javascript-override-methods. Perhaps that's what's happening here and the original author did just that, and it's exactly why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: To add to @goto1's comment: using `String.prototype.trim = () => 'Hello'` returns only `Hello` when you use `trim`.

Comment: Could you try adding the following code right before trim: `String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };` - it polyfills the correct "trim" function, which works for me. If it works with this, you know you have a bad trim for some reason.

Comment: Could you search for `String.prototype.trim` in the project and check if any overrides are added?

Comment: function myTrim(x) {
  return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

function myFunction() {
  var str = myTrim("        Hello World!        ");
  alert(str);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying your code in a regular browser show that it works as expected - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04ejgky2/).

## Is it possible to override the implementation of native trim() function in JavaScript?

Yes it is possible but it is considered a bad practice.
I'll show how to do that because I think the code has it overridden already.
Here is how to do it:

```
String.prototype.trim = x => console.log('trim override');
'olá'.trim(); // trim override
```

## What could be the reasons for this behavior?

Unless it's run in an unexpected environment it is most likely that the original author has `trim` overridden to something that is different from native implementation. I would suggest you try to paste the polyfill with original implementation in to the console and checking if running it with that will fix the issue.

Here is the polyfill:

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
  return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
};
console.log('olá'.trim());
```

If the output of this code gives you the correct result (not trimming `á`) you found the issue.

Comment: I would suggest figuring out where and why the polyfill was made, and fixing it from the root. This could break existing code if they wanted this behaviour.